# The number is smaller, fewer or less than?

Tags: word-usage, comparatives, comparisons, irregular, correlative-comparatives

I always make confusion about the correct usage of the comparative for "irregular" adjectives (I don't know if this is the correct term).

Recently I had to write "the number of X is ____ ?", while I wanted to say that the quantity of X this year is less than the quantity of X in the previous year.

So, which of the following would be correct? Are there forms that are grammatically correct but not used?

1. The number of students this year is *fewer* than the number of students last year
2. The number of students this year is *lesser* than the number of students last year
3. The number of students this year is *less* than the number of students last year
4. The number of students this year is *smaller* than the number of students last year

I know that *fewer* is used for countables (e.g. "I have fewer children than my friend", or "I have fewer cars than a billionaire would have"), while *less* for uncountable (e.g. "I have less money than my friend"). Am I correct on this?

So, since "the number" is countable, I would opt for 1, but I am not sure.

Comment: Why use "the number of students" or "the quantity of students"? Why not simply say "there are *fewer* students this year than there were last year"?

Comment: If you want to use "number", then your 3. is correct. The number of students this year is **less** than....

Comment: @PeterShor on the GMAT there are questions that say "the number of..." and you have to choose the proper following. You don't get to change "the number"

Comment: I would use _lower_.

Comment: If this is a GMAT question, it's a bad one. You can say that a *number* is either less than or smaller than another number, although [looking at Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=five+is+smaller+than%2C+five+is+less+than+&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfive%20is%20smaller%20than%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfive%20is%20less%20than%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cfive%20is%20smaller%20than%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfive%20is%20less%20than%3B%2Cc0), people usually say *less than*. So both (3) and (4) should be acceptable answers, but maybe (3) is best.

Comment: And another [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=number+of+children+is+lower%2Cnumber+of+children+is+fewer%2Cnumber+of+children+is+smaller%2Cnumber+of+children+is+less&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3), which actually gives some support to (1) — surprising me — and shows that (3) and (4) are both used relatively often, although (3) is most frequent.